# KDE Connect SMS has New button disabled

Tags: kde, kde-connect, sms

KDE Connect SMS shows the "New" button disabled. I can read SMS and reply but cannot create new text.

[image]

When I run kdeconnect-sms from terminal, I receive following messages

```
qrc:/qml/ConversationList.qml:51: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
qrc:/qml/ConversationList.qml:60: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/templates/InlineMessage.qml:257:9: QML ActionToolBar: Binding loop detected for property "atBottom"
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?